# Headers aren't being set on POST response

Tags: angular, go, cors

I've got a POST API endpoint written in Go, and I'm setting a header called Set-Cookie in the Golang response. I've set up cors and the call is returning the correct values. The problem is that the headers in the response are empty. If I look at my network tab, it says that my Set-Cookie header is being returned with the value I'm expecting, it's just in angular that it's empty (see screenshots of the console.log of my response.headers and my network tab).

## EDIT

adding a picture of what my cookies look like in chrome on subsequent requests after te Set-Cookie header has been set in golang. Doesn't look like chrome auto sets the cookies.

## EDIT

So, it definitely seems like it's a browser issue. When I hit the endpoint with postman the cookie is definitely set. I don't necessarily want to get the cookie in angular, I just want to set the cookie in the browser.

[image]

My angular code:

```
login(user): Subscription {
    return this.http
      .post(`${SERVICE_URL}/login`, user, {
        observe: 'response',
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
      })
      .subscribe((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
       console.log(response.headers);
      }, (response) => {
        this._user$.next(null);
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

my cors settings in the golang server using rs/cors

```
c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedMethods: []string{"GET","POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:4200", "localhost:4200"},
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization", "Set-Cookie"},
        ExposedHeaders: []string{"Set-Cookie"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    })
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your angular .post(…) call, try setting 'withCredentials: true'. (And by the way, the downvote’s not from me…)

Comment: The cookie is flagged as HttpOnly making it inaccessible with JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Directives

Comment: I just want it to set the cookie for the browser, I don't necessarily need to do it with angular.

Answer (score 0):

The browser (looks like chrome devtools) will **handle the cookie for you**. If you go looking in the application tab of the devtools you can find the cookies. If you need to get the value of that header in Angular, I suggest you **use a different header**. One that the browser doesn't intercept. It is good practise to namespace your header like `x-my-header`.

There isn't an api in Angular for manipulating the cookies, but there are packages out there that enable it like 'ngx-cookie-service'

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to set the cookie. I hit the endpoint that set the Set-Cookie header, and then hit another endpoint that outputs the values of the cookies of the request and it's empty. I'll post a picture in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact: I was setting `AllowCredentials: true` in the response, but I wasn't setting it in the Angular request. You need it in both places for chrome to set the cookie.